# Error: "OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found ..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I execute the following command:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    OpenRowset (
        'MSDASQL',
        'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt;*.csv)};DefaultDir=C:\;',
        'select top 10 * from C:\x.csv'
    )
```

... then Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio responds with:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified.

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on Win 7 x64. I've also tried it on Windows Vista x32, same error.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone successfully run this command on Win 7 x64?
2. Do any of you know what could be causing the T-SQL command to fail like this?

---

**Update 1:**

If you get an error that mentions "ad hoc queries", run the following to eliminate it:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

---

**Update 2:**

It works on an out-of-the-box Win7 x64 machine, but I still can't fix this error on my machine. I'll go with "bulk insert" (see my comments below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it on x64 Win7 and made it work.  I think there are a couple problems.

1. I believe you have to add a space
   between `*.txt;` and `*.csv`
2. Don't include the path with the file name

This worked:

```
select * from OpenRowset('MSDASQL', 
         'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DefaultDir=c:\;', 
         'select top 10 * from x.csv')
```

Comment: Darn. I just tried your exact same string, and it still gave the same error.

Comment: What .csv file did you try it with? Mine had just two words in it, separated by commas, e.g.: ten,four

Comment: That's odd.  Without the space between the *.txt and *.csv in the name, I got the exact same error you reported.

Comment: @Gravitas: I just now tried a file with only 'ten,four' in it and it worked.  The error you get seems to point at the driver itself not being recognized (or not installed correctly) rather than the file itself not being found.

Comment: I ended up going with "bulk insert" to do the job, and it works brilliantly. Bulk insert is probably more reliable, as there are no dependencies (it relies on functionality contained inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2). I'm going to award the answer to you, as all I wanted to know is whether it works on Win7 x64 out of the box. I'm sure if I reinstalled Win7 x64 it would start to work again. Having said this, there is a lot of chatter on the internet about this error - it seems that a whole ton of other people have had issues with this particular method and nobody really knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 15):

Solution: I've just wrestled with this issue for several hours on a Win7 x64 machine, and it is so difficult to find a good answer online that I thought I'd contribute one to this thread belatedly.

On my machine (Win7, x64, SQL Server 2008 R2), Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC) > Drivers, shows no driver called "Microsoft Text Driver". But there is a driver labeled "Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)"

I was able to change the driver name in code similar to the original questioner's INCLUDING the parentheses (*.txt, *.csv) WITH a comma and a space, not a semicolon. And it worked.

```
select 
    * 
from 
    OpenRowset (
        'MSDASQL',
        'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};DefaultDir=C:\;',
        'select top 10 * from C:\x.csv'
    )
```

Note that the syntax in specifying the drive must be exactly the same. I can vouch for that because I went through several wrong iterations.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm sure you'll help others users in the future.

Comment: Heh... at least that changes the symptoms for the problem I'm having.  Thank you for taking the time to post.

Comment: Freaking YES!  This one has stymied me forev-vur.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes! After hours of searching!