# Importing XML file into SQL Server 2000 using OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to import an XML fie into SQL Server 2000 (SP2) table. I tried below query and it's giving syntax error near the word `BULK`. Not entirely sure if `BULK` and `SINGLE_BLOB` work in SQL Server 2000 SP2.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'E:\temp\PersonData.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
```

Also tried below query....

```
SELECT * FROM   OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',  
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.xml)};DefaultDir=E:\temp\PersonData.xml;', 
'SELECT * FROM [PersonData.xml];' )
```

....and it gave this error:

> [OLE/DB provider returned message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified]
>   OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDASQL' IDBInitialize::Initialize returned 0x80004005:   ].

What am I doing wrong here? or Is it a SQL server 2000 issue?. My goal is to import an XML file into SQL Server using a stored procedure. Can't upgrade the server nor can I use a third party tool. Within these boundaries, please suggest me a way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPENROWSET(BULK ...)` was introduced in SQL Server 2005, so you can't use it.

`OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', ...)` is notorious for giving unhelpful error messages. See [Error: "OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011226/error-ole-db-provider-msdasql-for-linked-server-null-returned-message) for a related question; this suggests that the file name should not be part of the `DefaultDir` parameter (so `DefaultDir=E:\temp`).

If all else fails, you could use `BULK INSERT` with bogus values for the field and row terminators to read the entire file in a single `NTEXT` column; you can then use `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `OPENXML` to read it.

Comment: Nice call about using BULK INSERT. Worked. Thanks a lot